# ymd with vector of dates

Tags: r, lubridate

A simple question, I think.  I have some dates, `d`:

```
d <- as.POSIXct(c("2014-01-01 00:00:00 BST", "2014-01-01 00:30:00 BST"))
> class(d)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

If I try and extract just the date part with `lubridate`, it works fine with a single value but not the whole vector, i.e.:

```
> ymd(d[1])
[1] "2014-01-01 UTC"

> ymd(d)
[1] NA NA
Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
```

For the record, this works:

```
> as.Date(d, format="%F")
[1] "2014-01-01" "2014-01-01"
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that your vector is not just year, month, day (ymd), but also hour, minute, second (hms). Consider using this instead:

```
ymd_hms(d)
```

If you want to just extract the date, you can use:

```
strftime(ymd_hms(d),'%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: Oh, maybe I misunderstood.  I thought that, in addition to guessing the date format of a text string, it would also extract the date from a POSIXct object, like `month()`.